# Flip Animation - Backface visibility not working

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, css-transforms

So I'm currently implementing some flip animation on a few elements within my project.

I have achieved the animation via CSS and ontouchstart attribute with hover. However, the backface of the card or element is never shown. But when I created the following JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pueg0uxm/

This is the effect I'm trying complete but this code isn't working within my project for some reason.

The only other classes I have that might be effecting it is the following;

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="child" style="animation-delay: 6.5s;">
            <div class="front" ng-style={'backgroundimage':'url(/assets/02_BRANDING.jpg)'}">
                <h1 class="feature-text">RETAIL<br/>DESIGN</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <div>
                   <h1 >Portland...</h1>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

.child {
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 50%;
    width: 25%;
    max-width: calc(100% * (1/4));
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex-flow: nowrap row;
    flex-flow: nowrap row;
}
```

Here is a gif of what is happening compared to the JSFiddle with the same code;

[image]

As you can see the backface is still visible and not the code which is within the back class and div.

Comment: There is some issue with your code, can you create a fiddle for this.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I mean full code including html and css.

Comment: There's a fiddle above. https://jsfiddle.net/pueg0uxm/

Comment: That's working perfectly fine over-there.

Comment: I know that's what I said in my comment's above lol :D. I don't understand why it's working in the fiddle and not in my project. Ive shown you the child class from my project's code as that's the only difference between the fiddle and my src files.